# Remove id in Facebook login in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am developing an android app which can be used via Facebook login. I did it and also able to  get the Friend list. But with friend list I am getting ID also of friends with their name. I don't want it.I just want their names. My code is below. What am I missing?

```
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (session.isOpened()) {
            Request.executeMyFriendsRequestAsync(session, new GraphUserListCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users, Response response) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int i = 0, j;
                    i = users.size();

                    // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "" + i,
                    // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                        ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>(
                            Arrays.asList(response.toString()));

                            ArrayAdapter<String> string = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr);
                            lv.setAdapter(string);
                            string.setNotifyOnChange(true);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

---

I have done till this in which I am getting only one Friend name and nothing else. Succeeded to get only name and not ID. But I am just getting one name. What am I missing again?

```
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void call(final Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (session.isOpened()) {

                Request.executeMyFriendsRequestAsync(session,
                        new GraphUserListCallback() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users,
                                    Response response) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                for (GraphUser user : users) {


                                     ArrayList<String> arr = new
                                     ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(user.getName()));
                                     ArrayAdapter<String> str = new
                                     ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),
                                     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arr);
                                     lv.setAdapter(str);
                                     str.setNotifyOnChange(true);

                                }

                            }
                        });

            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ID` is an unique parameter, and you will get that in your result of any API you call.

Comment: Btw, how does this ID is bothering?

Comment: Because I just want name of friends and nothing else.